# Odoo: dynamic domain filters results only once

Tags: python, odoo-12

I am trying to pass a domain dynamically to a `many2one` field using an `onchange` function. It manages to retrieve the desired results (filtering the results as desired), but it does it only once. In other words, the `onchange` function succeeds to bring to filter the results according to the first selection only and any preceding selection doesn't seem to affect the domain filtering.

Code:

```
class ReturnProduct(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.return.product'
    sale_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="custom.sale", string="Invoice #", required=False, )
    return_line_ids = fields.One2many("custom.return.line", "return_product_id", string="Products")

class ReturnLine(models.Model):
    _name = "custom.return.line"
    return_product_id = fields.Many2one("custom.return.product", string="Return Reference")
    sale_line_id = fields.Many2one("custom.sale.line", string="Product")
    reason = fields.Text(String="Return Reason")

    @api.onchange('return_product_id')
    def onchange_product_id(self):
        domain = {}
        sale_line_ids = []
        if self._context.get('sale_id'):
            sale_id = self.env["custom.sale"].browse(self._context.get('sale_id'))
            for sale_line in sale_id.product_ids.ids:
                sale_line_ids.append(sale_line)
        domain = {'sale_line_id': [('id', 'in', sale_line_ids)]}
        return {'domain': domain}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to filter products in the return wizard based on products in sale line. You need products in the sale line to be appeared in the return product line

For that you can do the below

```
@api.onchange('return_product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    domain = {}
    product_ids = []
    if self._context.get('sale_id'):
        sale_id = self.env["custom.sale"].browse(self._context.get('sale_id'))
        for sale_line in sale_id.product_ids:
            product_ids.append(sale_line)
    domain = {'return_product_id': [('id', 'in', product_ids)]}
    return {'domain': domain}
```

So actually you want to set domain for product.

Comment: my problem isn't with the result of filtering, my problem is that it does the job right but only once
it doesn't update the ```many2one``` field with the new results

Comment: this is supposed to be an "Item return" model ```custom.return.product```, where a salesman selects a sales invoice (model ```custom.sale```) upon which the products that belong to this sales order should be tabulated in the ```one2many``` field ```sale_line_id ``` . These products ```id``` is already saved in the model ```custom.sale.line``` along with the quantity ordered and sale invoice number

Comment: I understood. In certain cases filtering will not work properly inside one2many. So better to create a many2many field to the model 'product.product' in he one2many inside the 'custom.return.line'. and put domain based on this new product field. Please try to update this new product field with al products in the sale line, each time when the wizard opens